# Conditinal Formatting Odoo form view

Tags: css, xml, forms, odoo

I want to achieve the below scenario. Have tried in many ways but no luck.

```
<t t-if="q1_percent &gt; 75">
    <td style="background-color:#52be80"><field name="q1_percent" nolabel="1"/></td>
</t>
<t t-elif="'q1_percent' &gt; 50 and 'q1_percent' &lt; 75">
    <td class="td_act" style="background-color:#f4d03f"><field name="q1_percent" nolabel="1"/></td>
</t>
<t t-elif="'q1_percent' &lt; 50">
    <td class="td_act" style="background-color:#e74c3c"><field name="q1_percent" nolabel="1"/></td>
</t>
```

I am using odoo 10. And the above code is for form view.

How can I achieve this? Any ideas any help is most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until Odoo 12 There is a difference between a regular view(tree, form, etc) and a QWeb view meaning that regular views cannot be mixed with QWeb content to be evaluated as for Reports and Website Pages.

You still could be able to acquire what you are looking for by simply defining a computed HTML Field that will contains the HTML result of evaluate that QWeb code or directly build the HTML without using QWeb at all. Or without QWeb just generating the HTML by yourself.

For example:

```py
from lxml import etree

q1_percent_html = fields.HTML("Q1 Percent HTML", compute='_compute_q1_percent_html')

@api.depends('q1_percent')
def _compute_q1_percent_html(self):
    for elem in self:
        # QWeb version
        t = etree.fromstring("""
            <div>
                <t t-if="q1_percent &gt; 75">
                    <td style="background-color:#52be80"><t t-esc="q1_percent"/></td>
                </t>
                <t t-elif="'q1_percent' &gt; 50 and 'q1_percent' &lt; 75">
                    <td class="td_act" style="background-color:#f4d03f"><t t-esc="q1_percent"/></td>
                </t>
                <t t-elif="'q1_percent' &lt; 50">
                    <td class="td_act" style="background-color:#e74c3c"><t t-esc="q1_percent"/></td>
                </t>
            <div>
        """)
        elem.q1_percent_html = self.env['ir.qweb'].render(t, {'q1_percent': elem.q1_percent})

        # Python direct version
        if elem.q1_percent >= 75:
            background_color = "#52be80"
        elif elem.q1_percent >= 50 and elem.q1_percent <= 75:
            background_color = "#f4d03f"
        elif elem.q1_percent <= 50:
            background_color = "#e74c3c"
        elem.q1_percent_html = """<div><td style="background-color:%s">%s</td></div>"""% (background_color, elem.q1_percent)
```

Use that field in your form view like:

```xml
<field name="q1_percent_html" nolabel="1" readonly="1"/>
```